# How to pause stories in react-insta-stories?

Tags: react-insta-stories

I'm working with react-insta-stories and passing the prop of isPaused but my stories keeps playing. Here is my component

````
const [isPause, setIsPause] = useState(false);

// Toggle the state on button click:
const handlePauseToggle = () => {
  setIsPause(!isPause);
};

// Render the ReactInstaStories component:
<ReactInstaStories
  stories={storySlides}
  defaultInterval={5000}
  width={xs ? 350 : 500}
  height={xs ? 500 : 600}
  currentIndex={currentSlide}
  loop
  isPaused={isPause}
  storyContainerStyles={{ background: 'transparent'}}
/>```

My isPause state is changing but stories dont pause. I have also used Stories component from react-insta-stories and used isPaused as documented in its documentation but its not working. Can anyone Please help me here.
````